# Nested LinearLayout are not shown inside InfoWindowsAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps on Android app. In the map I've some marker; when you click on them I want display a custom InfoWindowsAdapter that show this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_nome"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_indirizzo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIndirizzo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_orario"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOrario"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="--" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_servizi"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textServizi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="--" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the part of the code of Activity:

```
 public class InfoAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    View contenuto;

    InfoAdapter() {
        contenuto = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        render(marker, contenuto);
        return contenuto;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        if (view != null) {
            TextView textNome = (TextView) contenuto.findViewById(R.id.textNome);
            TextView textIndirizzo = (TextView)       contenuto.findViewById(R.id.textIndirizzo);
            TextView textOrario = (TextView) contenuto.findViewById(R.id.textOrario);

            textIndirizzo.setText("Indirizzo");
            textNome.setText("Nome");
            textOrario.setText("07:00 - 19:00");
        }
    }
}
```

***The problem:*** when you click on the marker you see the custom view but is show only the first LinearLayout that show textNome. In substance overy LinearLayout is a row and I can see always only the first.

Using a classic view outside Google Maps this view works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_nome"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_indirizzo"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textIndirizzo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_orario"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOrario"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"
        android:text="@string/wc_servizi"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textServizi"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="17dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```